# How is this possible in mole concept?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, atoms, molecules, mole

L = $6.022*10^{23}$[image]

If I have one atom of oxygen , it has exactly L value.

Now 2 atoms of a oxygen have 2L value.(Note that I mean 2O and not $O_2$here)

Well , if we take a molecule made up of 2atoms or combined i.e ($O_2$It also has L value. How is that possible ?It has bigger size and probably more atoms.

Reference :Take a look at the table
[image]

[image]

Comment: What's an L value? I don't think it is a thing at all.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Just 1st image last line

Comment: Well, Avogadro number is just a number. Admittedly, a big one, but still a number. It has no magic powers. Substitute it everywhere with "thousand", and then the confusion must vanish.

Comment: As of 2019 the [Avogadro constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant#SI_redefinition_of_2019) is no longer based on 12 g of C-12. It is now just a specific number: $6.02214076 \times 10^{23}$.

Comment: @MaxW yes.This is right

Comment: In the US the  Avogadro constant is normally denoted as $\mathrm{N_A}$. In Germany $\mathrm{L}$ seems to be the norm. See IUPAC Goldbook [Avogadro constant](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00543)

Comment: @MaxW Be aware there is the tiny difference between the unitless Avogadro number and the Avogadro constant with unit 1/mol.

Comment: What is the title and author of that horrible textbook, and what is the intended audience?

Comment: ICSE class 10.Viraj F dalal is the author.2019 edition.@Karl

Comment: @Karl audience are students who are preparing for national level exam of ICSE board.@Karl

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education ? Figures. Isn't India still in the Commonwealth? Can't your officials let you use *British* books, instead of developing crappy homemade substitutes?

Comment: Sorry for the rant. ;-)

Comment: @Karl, Many Commonwealth countries allow O-levels and A-levels where British books are used. It is equivalent to grade 10, 11-12, but it is not popular among the masses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCE_Ordinary_Level#India

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to see that this is your grade 10 textbook. This also means you have no choice but to use this book for passing public exams. Please don't use L or *NA* as a symbol.

> If I have one atom of oxygen , it has exactly L value.

**No.** Atoms are discrete objects i.e., countable. If you have 1 atom of oxygen, it means 1 atom of oxygen. If you said 1 mole of oxygen atoms, then it is 6.022x10$^{23}$ atoms of oxygen.

Your *L* comes from Loschmidt number or constant. From Science Progress in the Twentieth Century (1919-1933) , **1933**, Vol. 27, pp. 634-649

> Loschmidt 's number, N, is defined as the number of atoms in gram-atom
> or the number of molecules in a gram-molecule.More than eighty
> different experimental determinations of this number have been made
> [i], and as it is a basic atomic constant its most probable value is
> of great importance in atomic physics. It is, therefore, the purpose
> of this article to outline the main methods by which Loschmidťs number
> has been evaluated, and to give some indication of current opinions of
> its most probable value
>
> **Footnote**
>
> 1 This number is frequently referred to as " Avogadro's Number/' the
> term " Loschmidťs Number " being then reserved for the number of mole-
> cules in a cubic centimetre of a gas under standard conditions.
> Unfortunately, these designations are often interchanged. Avogadro's
> important hypothesis on the identity of the numbers of molecules in
> equal volumes of different gases at the same pressure and temperature
> was formulated in 1811, and is appropriately associated with his name
> ; but Avogadro made no quantitative estimate of either of the
> above-mentioned constants. The first actual estimate of the number of
> molecules in one cubic centimetre of a gas under standard conditions
> was made in 1865 by Loschmidt, and from this the number of molecules
> (atoms) in a gram molecule (atom) was later evaluated. From the
> quantitative view-point it thus seems preferable to speak of "
> Loschmidťs number per gram-molecule (atom)/' and of " Loschmidťs
> number per cubic centimetre," as is almost invariably done in the
> German scientific literature. This terminology avoids ambiguity, and
> has been adopted here.

You can see here your textbook is using the symbolism of 1930s or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

**A mole is just a number, but you have to specify what you are counting**

Aside from problematic issues about how your textbook is explaining things, the central misunderstanding arises because you need to specify *what* you are counting when you say there is a mole of something.

If you are counting oxygen *atoms* then there are two moles of *oxygen* atoms in one mole of *dioxygen gas*. There is no magic or confusion *if you specify what it is you are counting*.

This is not a problem unique to chemistry. If you count eggs, for example, you might use a dozen eggs (a dozen is just a signifier for 12 of anything) to make one (large) omelette. There is no confusion if you are clear about what you are counting, omelettes or eggs.

A mole is just a number, like a dozen (but a lot bigger). Indeed, you could have a mole (the number) of moles (the small burrowing mammal) but this would be [enough matter to form a small planet](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/).